# VB application says argument not specified for parameter

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Function Calc(ByVal a As Decimal, ByVal Grams As Decimal) As Decimal
    ' declare variables and convert to decimal
    Grams = txtGrams.Text
    a = Grams
    Grams = a * 31.1035
    Return Grams
End Function

Private Function Calcul(ByVal b As Decimal, ByVal Ounces As Decimal) As Decimal
    Ounces = txtTroyOunces.Text
    b = Ounces
    Ounces = b * 0.911458
    Return Ounces
End Function

Private Sub btnConvert_Click(sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnConvert.Click
    ' determine if text boxes txtGrams and txtTroyOunces is empty
    If IsNumeric(txtGrams.Text) Then
        txtGrams.Text = Calc(txtGrams.Text)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number")
    End If
End Sub
```

Think I am so close but is says argument not specified for parameter `Grams`.

Comment: Considering that you are clobbering the `a` parameter with a new value before you use what was passed as the parameter, there's probably not much point having it as a parameter.  And considering that you are also clobbering the `Grams` parameter with a new value, there isn't much point having that as a parameter either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code so here I try to provide code that compiles and also does what I believe you intend your code to do.

The first function converts from grams to troy ounces so I have named it accordingly. The only purpose of the function is to perform a multiplication so it might be a bit overkill. However, notice that I append `D` to the constant. This is a `Decimal` literal. If you do not append this it is instead a `Double` literal. This means that there will be a conversion from the input `Decimal` value to a `Double` value before the multiplication is performed. The resulting `Double` will then be converted back to a `Decimal` value when it is returned from the function. When you use `Decimal` values you normally want to avoid this loss of precision.

```
Private Function ConvertGramsToTroyOunces(ByVal grams As Decimal) As Decimal
    Return grams*31.1035
End Function
```

The other function (which isn't used) becomes:

```
Private Function ConvertOuncesToTroyOunces(ByVal ounces As Decimal) As Decimal
    Return ounces*0.911458D
End Function
```

The button click handler inspects the text box to see if the value is a number and then calls the function to perform the conversion before storing the result in the text box again:

```
Private Sub btnConvert_Click(sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnConvert.Click
    Dim grams As Decimal
    If Decimal.TryParse(txtGrams.Text, grams)
        txtGrams.Text = ConvertGramsToTroyOunces(grams)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number")
    End If
End Sub
```

I don't use the `IsNumeric` function which I believe is a "legacy" Visual Basic function you have implemented yourself. Instead I use `Decimal.TryParse` to both check the input and perform the conversion in one go.

Comment: Thank you I added another if statement for the txttroyounces and it works like a charm. Racking my head over this for a few days trying different methods. It looks like I over thought it again. I have a habit of doing that.

Answer (score 3):

You're only passing one argument here:

```
Calc(txtGrams.Text)
```

To a function which expects two:

```
Private Function Calc(ByVal a As Decimal, ByVal Grams As Decimal) As Decimal
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It makes **several** improvements to what you have:

```
Private Function TroyOuncesFromGrams(ByVal Grams As Decimal) As Decimal
    Return Grams * 31.1034768D
End Function

Private Function TroyOuncesFromStdOunces(ByVal Ounces As Decimal) As Decimal
    Return Ounces * 0.911458D
End Function

Private Sub btnConvert_Click(sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnConvert.Click
    ' determine if text boxes txtGrams and txtTroyOunces is empty
    Dim input As Decimal
    If Decimal.TryParse(txtGrams.Text, input)
        txtGrams.Text = ConvertGrams(input).ToString()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number")
    End If
End Sub
```

**And make sure you have `Option Strict` or `Option Infer` turned on!** That would have caught most of the errors for you already.

I'd also be tempted to use a `Module` or even a `Struct` that shadows the `Decimal` type for this:

```
Public Struct TroyOunce 

    'TODO: Implements directives for IEquatable, IConvertable, IComparable, etc to match Decimal, plus addition/subtraction operators and overloads for GetHashCode(), Equals(), CompareTo() etc

    Public Property Value As Decimal

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(quantity As Decimal)
        Value = quantity
    End Sub

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal ounces As TroyOunce) As Decimal
        Return ounces.Value
    End Operator

    Public Shared Narrowing Operator CType(ByVal ounces As TroyOunce) As Double
        Return CDbl(ounces.Value)
    End Operator

    Public Shared Narrowing Operator CType(ByVal ounces As TroyOunce) As Integer
        Return CInt(ounces.Value)
    End Operator

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal ounces As Decimal) As TroyOunce
        Return New TroyOunce(ounces)
    End Operator

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal ounces As Double) As TroyOunce
        Return New TroyOunce(CDec(ounces))
    End Operator

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal ounces As Integer) As TroyOunce
        Return New TroyOunce(CDec(ounces))
    End Operator

    Public Shared Function FromGrams(grams As Decimal) As TroyOunce
        Return New TroyOunce(grams * 31.1034768D)
    End Function

    Public Shared Function FromStdOunces(ounces As Decimal) As TroyOunce
        Return New TroyOunce(ounces* 0.911458D)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ToString()
         Return Value.ToString()
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ToString(provider As IFormatProvider)
         Return Value.ToString(provider)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ToString(format As String)
         Return Value.ToString(format)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ToString(format As String, provider As IFormatProvider)
        Return Value.ToString(format, provider)
    End Function

End Struct
```

When the Struct is done, you can for the most part treat it just like a Decimal, and your Click event will look like this:

```
Private Sub btnConvert_Click(sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnConvert.Click
    ' determine if text boxes txtGrams and txtTroyOunces is empty
    Dim input As Decimal
    If Decimal.TryParse(txtGrams.Text, input)
        txtGrams.Text = TroyOunce.FromGrams(input).ToString()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number")
    End If
End Sub
```